# Can I integrate Skype (or Skype for Business) into my web app on Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, skype

I have a web app on my Azure AD B2C directory, and would like to know if I can integrate Skype or Skype for Business feature into my app to enable users have a group text/voice chat.

Ideally, any user who logs in to my web app using an OAuth2 identity (Microsoft, Google, Facebook or else) could be hop on the text/voice chat system with single-sign-on (e.g., one can start a conversation with a specific group of users that either my web app assigns to the user or he selects on the app.)

There seems Skype can be added as an enterprise application to Azure AD, but I'm not sure if it means users can use it with the credential of my website using AD B2C.

Any suggestions, or do I need further specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Federate AAD and AAD B2C using custom policies
- If Skype supports this, add via either SAML or OpenID Connect. You can do this using custom policies or via the OIDC entry under the Identites tag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I go the first option, can users use the credentials of my AD B2C to use the skype online application? (Say, can they use their Google account which is used to login to my website via OAuth2 to use the app?)

Comment: They would be logging in with their AAD account to your app. AAD supports Skype. They could log into AAD with their Google account. Not sure how that account integrates into Skype? Maybe as a guest?

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.